# How to change master detail theme from static data to dynamic data?

Tags: java, android

When you create a new android project with the master detail theme you get a class DummyContent with dummy static data:

```
package com.test.masterdetail.dummy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Helper class for providing sample content for user interfaces created by
 * Android template wizards.
 * <p>
 * TODO: Replace all uses of this class before publishing your app.
 */
public class DummyContent {

    /**
     * An array of sample (dummy) items.
     */
    public static List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<DummyItem>();

    /**
     * A map of sample (dummy) items, by ID.
     */
    public static Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, DummyItem>();

    static {
        // Add 3 sample items.
        addItem(new DummyItem("1", "Item 1", "http://www.yahoo.com"));
        addItem(new DummyItem("2", "Item 2", "http://www.fb.com"));
        addItem(new DummyItem("3", "Item 3", "http://www.google.com"));
    }

    private static void addItem(DummyItem item) {
        ITEMS.add(item);
        ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
    }

    /**
     * A dummy item representing a piece of content.
     */
    public static class DummyItem {
        public String id;
        public String content;
        public String url;

        public DummyItem(String id, String content, String url) {
            this.id = id;
            this.content = content;
            this.url = url;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return content;
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to change this data from static to dynamic that I will be providing from the database. Anyone can give me some pointers?

Comment: Do you mean with "dynamic" non static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method to add content:

```
/**
 * call the method setContext from my main activity at the beginning of the onCreate method, before any other operation.
 */
public static void setContext() {
    addItem(new DummyItem(var1, var2, var3,...));
}
```

but remember to call notifyDataSetChanged:

```
// Update the list of the fragment
((YourListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id)).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

right after calling:

```
DummyContent.setContext();
```